# youtube-dl --keep-fragments option does not save fragments

Tags: video, youtube, video-streaming, youtube-dl

I could find few questions about the method to save framents (DASH video segements) while downloading a video using youtube-dl. Including the youtube-dl Git only specify that use of --keep-fragments to download the video should store the individual fragments in the download folder alng with the complete video. I need to download the fragments video from download for research purpose. I use the following command:

```
youtube-dl -f 160 --keep-fragments https://youtu.be/amidG4XFqDY
```

However I don't see the video fragment in the directory. I can only see the `tearsofsteel 4k-amidG4XFqDY.mp4.part` while file being downloaded and `tearsofsteel 4k-amidG4XFqDY.mp4` after download is complete. I can not see individual fragments saved in the directory.

Is this something related to the container mentioned in youtube-dl format list as :

> 160          mp4        256x114    144p   79k , ***mp4_dash container***,
> avc1.4d400c@  79k, 24fps, video only, 6.91MiB

Or something related to video resolution?

I was able to save the fragments before in year 2020 using this command for different video. However I am not able to save the fragement with the latest youtube-dl version

```
youtube-dl --version
2021.12.17
```

Please help if I am missing something or anyone has experienced something similar.

----edit-----
I am using the youtubedl using python. I am not using ffmpeg. I have observe that if the video resolution is 1080p max --keep-fragments works. but it does not work for higher resolution. I am not sure if that is true for all users.

Answer (score 0):

The --keep-fragments option only seems to work if it's youtube-dl itself doing the capturing.  If it's delegating the capture to something like ffmpeg, then it has no effect.

Comment: I am using the youtubedl using python. I am not using ffmpeg.
I have observe that if the video resolution is 1080p max  --keep-fragments works. but it does not work for higher resolution. I am not sure if that is true for all users.